# What is the word meaning: The best example of something? Not epitome. I heard someone describe a word, latin base?, with this meaning

Tags: single-word-requests, meaning

This word was mentioned in a discussion about words that had once been used in history.  I believe he said that this word had a Latin base.  I believe, after capturing my attention a little late, that the word started with sak(?) and ended with ger(?).  It was a word he believed should be brought back into usage.  I agree.  Epitome, for me, just doesn't have the connotation best suited for certain, such, 'examples' that i have in mind.

Wouldn't we think that there should be at least a few words that would describe such a noteworthy thing in life and living?  The Best Example, Representation, of a thing, of something, of a condition, of a situation, of a sense, a feeling, a belief, a POV/Point of View?

Comment: have you looked up synonyms to 'epitome'?

Comment: _Prototype_ is a possibility.

Comment: What examples do you "have in mind" that *epitome* doesn't fit? "She is the epitome of beauty" works: what is a case which would allow people to fit your word?

Comment: 'Paradigm' appears in a list of synonyms for 'example', as does John Lawler's suggestion. / A word that is now obsolete isn't going to be much use, as the overriding connotations will be 'arcane' / 'weird'. // You may be half-remembering **sockdolager** {NOUN US  informal 
1 A forceful blow.

2 **An exceptional person or thing.** {[ODO](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/sockdolager)}}

Comment: The word you heard may have been _quintessential_. See MW.

Comment: This is what we call a "guessing game" question. They're not a good fit for the site – or, to my knowledge, any SE site. ([more](https://stackoverflow.blog/2012/02/lets-play-the-guessing-game/))

Answer (score 1):

[***Exemplar***](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=exemplar&oq=exemplar&aqs=chrome..69i57.2420j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8), perhaps.

So, for example, as applied to people -

*A person whose conduct is regarded as an object of imitation or as an influence on the behaviour of others; esp. a person considered worthy of imitation; a paragon of a particular quality or virtue.*

Example usages from the OED show how widely it has been used:

> 1920   R. Fry in Burlington Mag. Oct. 162/2   *The **exemplar** which men put before themselves was the civilization of Greece and Rome*.

1975   B. Gill Here at New Yorker 27   *Ross liked to be thought of as an **exemplar** of common sense*.

> 2004   Internat. Gas Engin. & Managem. May 9/2   *The European Commission..singled out the UK programme as an **exemplar** to follow*.

2009   Time Out N.Y. 12 Mar. 47/1   *Levittown, the Long Island housing development,..became a Stepfordlike **exemplar** of postwar suburbia*.

And, of course, exemplars are ***exemplary*** -

*A model for imitation, a pattern, a prototype; someone or something to be imitated; esp. a person whose conduct is considered worthy of imitation.*(OED)